# How should I insulate crawlspace joist bay for water supply lines?

Tags: plumbing, insulation, crawlspace

I am renovating a kitchen in my new home, which involves the job of moving the kitchen sink to a space to the floor above the crawl space. In order to do this, I need to run water supply lines ~ 10 feet from the poured basement through the floor pocket in the crawl space. What are the ways to do this to avoid potential freezing? My home is in the northeastern United States where average winter temperatures are around 20 degrees F at night.

Some things I plan on doing:

- Using 1/2" PEX
- Angling the supply lines at a slight incline, with a drain elbow at the bottom so I can drain water if severe cold weather is happening.
- Insulating the floor pocket with R30.
- Adding heat tape.

What are some things I can do to further prevent freezing?

Comment: Have you considered adding heat tape?

Comment: Yes, that is on my list as well. EDIT added.

Answer (score 2):

Run the pipes against the floor, (or at least above the insulation), so they are at house temperature, not outside temperature or somewhere in between. Slightly below the floor might be better if you anticipate driving nails into the floor, or you could use 1/16" steel plate against the floor to protect the pipes in the usual way.

Other than that, more insulation is always better.

Comment: More insulation isn't _always_ better. If you're compressing fiberglass you're reducing thermal resistance, possibly to the point of reduced effectiveness compared to less insulation. Otherwise, I agree. It's simply a matter of keeping pipes inside the building envelope.

Comment: More insulation, not "more insulation *material* improperly deployed." This particular bay might be a good place to whip out the polyisocyanurate sheets (or add one to the bottom of the bay, overlapping the joists a bit under mineral wool.

Comment: The overall r-value can go down for a product from specified but the actual r-value per inch can be higher if compressed.  R49 product installed in 14" is R3.5 per inch.  R49 product installed in 11.875" is R44 but R3.7 per inch so you actually get a better insulation value by compressing.  https://dcpd6wotaa0mb.cloudfront.net/mdms/dms/Residential%20Insulation/10017857/10017857-Building-Insul-Compressed-R-Value-Chart-Tech-Bulletin.pdf